# How to prevent FBO rendering corrupting when running multiple OpenGL processes at same time?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I need to be able to render with multiple processes at same time, using OpenGL.

I'm using FBO to render into a texture. I read the pixels by glGetTexImage() multiple times in that one process (tiled rendering).

Then I launched multiple programs to run at same time and noticed that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes the whole image is corrupted (repeats only one tile), sometimes only small part is corrupted. I also noticed earlier that I was not able to use 4096x4096 size FBO texture for some reason, and the errors from that texture size was same as this "multiple processes at once" tiling error, so I thought it could be something to do with the program trying to get a texture that is not yet fully rendered at all? I also noticed that the smaller texture I use, the more processes I can run at the same time. My GFX card memory is 256 MB I think. But even with 8 processes of 1024x1024 size texture size it uses only 33 MB of memory at worst, so it cant be my GFX card memory limitations.

The tiling error looks like it doesn't get the new tile pixel data, so it uses the old buffer again.

What can I do to prevent the corruption of my rendering?

Here is my rendering code structure:

```
for(y...){
    for(x...){
        // set viewport & translatef

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
        // glclear()
        render_tile();
        glFlush();
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        copy_tile_pixels_to_output_image();
    }
}
```

And here is the FBO initialization (only opengl related commands are shown):

```
// texture:
glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

// FBO:
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboId);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboId);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboId);

checkFramebufferStatus(); // will exit if errors found. none found, however.

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

**Edit:** as datenwolf noticed, the problem goes away by using glReadPixels(). But im not still sure why, so it would be good to know whats happening under the hood, to be sure it will not make such errors in **any case** in the future!

Comment: Why not simply use glReadPixels on the still bound FBO to retrieve the pixels?

Comment: @datenwolf, i got the glReadPixels() work now, and... i cant see rendering errors anymore! how come the texture method did make errors?

Comment: @datenwolf, how come i still need this line for the FBO: `glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);` and thus i need to allocate the texture too. Is there any way to get rid of that, now when i use glReadPixels?

Comment: Are these separate OpenGL contexts, or are they all part of the same share group?

Comment: @NicolBolas, i guess they are separate; i run the program.exe multiple times, so each is in its own process.

Comment: @Rookie: What's happening "under the hood" is simply a driver bug. Different OpenGL contexts should not affect each other. As for your question of why you need to attach a color texture to the framebuffer to read from it, well, what would you be reading/writing if you *didn't* have a color attachment? If you don't put *something* there to render to, then you can't write colors as a result of rendering. And you therefore can't read them. It doesn't have to be a *texture* anymore, since you're not using `glGetTexImage`. But you do need to put *something* there, texture or renderbuffer.

Comment: @Rookie: The FBO itself is just an abstract object without its own backing image storage. Basically the FBO itself consists of only slots into which you can plug image sinks and sources. Textures can act as such, but there are also renderbuffers, which serve kind of the same purpose, but cannot be used as a texturing sample source.

Comment: @datenwolf, i see. maybe post as an answer so i can accept that? :) Edit: this is weird, i still get some artifacts, but i can prevent them by using only 2048x2048 texture buffer, larger than that makes errors :S it displays 1 pixel thick line of semi-random pixels there (has same color as my texture colors). still not completely sure does that prevent all artifacts, but so far it does. i also earlier noticed that 2048x2048 size texture had least problems, maybe my gfx card is just broken...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FBO itself is just an abstract object without its own backing image storage. Basically the FBO itself consists of only slots into which you can plug image sinks and sources. Textures can act as such, but there are also renderbuffers, which serve kind of the same purpose, but cannot be used as a texturing sample source

You can read back directly from a bound FBO using glReadPixels.

Comment: yeah, glReadPixels() fixed it, apparently it was a driver bug.